# Gradle java plugin - analoge of productFlavors as on android plugin

Tags: gradle

I have **`MySpecific.java`** that has different content for 2 projects (`proj#1`, `proj#2`).
And I need to build different version of this file for every project.
In Android plugin for this reason I can use **productFlavors** : 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

It's very powerfull tool.

I copy **`MySpecific.java`** to 2 directories:

```
src/proj#1/java/com/mycompany/myproject/widget/MySpecific.java
```

and

```
src/proj#2/java/com/mycompany/myproject/widget/MySpecific.java
```

And when I build `proj#1` I use `productFlavor "proj#1"` and in final distributive I has **`MySpecific.java`** from directory:

```
proj#1/java/com/mycompany/myproject/widget/MySpecific.java
```

And when I build `proj#2` I use `productFlavor "proj#2"` and in final distributive I has **`MySpecific.java`** from directory:

```
proj#2/java/com/mycompany/myproject/widget/MySpecific.java
```

And this is very good.

The question is : 
When I work with pure java project, has gradle java plugin something like **productFlavors**?

Answer (score 0):

This is not available by default.

**What you can do is to define additional sourcesets and use them to compile and add to the final JARs.**

Comment: I think sourcesets not help.
So I need 2 version of MyCustom.java. This file has different content for every flavors. So I create e.g. flavor "my_flavor" and copy MyCustom.java from src\main\java\com\mycompany\myproject\client\ui\MyCustom.java
to

src\my_flavor\java\com\mycompany\myproject\client\ui\MyCustom.java.              But java compiler throw error:

The type MyCustom is already defined MyCustom.java /src/my_flavor/java/com/mycompany/myproject/client/ui/ line 75 Java Problem

also when I run via gradle

gradlew my_flavorjar

I also get same compile error